# When 'a' should be the value returned, 'a+1' is saved instead

Tags: ios, swift, int

I know that this may sound a bit silly, but I am facing the situation as stated in the title. When I open the Xcode playground and test out the value, it is working as expected, there is nothing wrong. However, when part of my iOS code run it, the value becomes larger by one.

To illustrate clearer, part of the code looks something like the following (`numberOfLists` is an array):

```
if numberOfLists.count == 0 {
    listIndex = Int16(0)
} else {
    listIndex = Int16(numberOfLists.count)
}
print(listIndex)
```

When I print out the value of `listIndex`, when I expect it to be 0, it prints 1; when I expect it to be a certain positive integer, let's say, `a`, the printed value is `a+1`. It seems like the "+1" is **consistent**.

Has anyone encountered this situation before?

Comment: I would print out `numberOfLists` and see what values are in it that you don't expect. You can be very certain that `.count` is not broken. There is one extra element in the array that you didn't expect.

Comment: The error ins't sounds in your posted code, please, post the logic code.

Comment: Your `if` statement is also very surprising. If `numberOfLists.count` were 0, wouldn't the second assignment still be correct? Why the `if`? Is it possible you're forgetting that arrays are 0-indexed? (i.e. in an array of 1 element, that element is at index 0?)

Comment: @RobNapier Thanks for the suggestion, it turns out that the problem is with `numberOfLists`. I use Coredata and fetch `numberOfLists`. The problem now is that when I initialize it with `[NumberOfLists]()`, which its `count` is `0`, but after I fetch the `NumberOfLists`, and assign the fetched array to the value (because initially I did not save any `NumberOfLists` value yet), the count bumps to `1`. I remove the built app in simulator and clean the project, [NumberOfLists] `count` is not 0. Why is it that when I fetch, the array's count is always one more than the actual count?

Comment: I'm certain that the array count is not one more than the actual count. I'm betting that there's an element in the array that you're assigning. Most likely there's an element you're not expecting.